# Paypal REST API, get sale exchange rate

Tags: node.js, rest, api, paypal

I'm using PayPal-node-SDK in a NodeJs app to get my ecommerce's sales' fees.

The problem is that I also need to get the exchange rate for each transaction ID, since I'm selling in USD and EUR.

I see those values in the Paypal Dashboard inside every transaction details, but how can I get it through APIs?

[image: conversion usd eur]

Comment: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/v1/#sale-get-response?mark=exchan here they have a field called `exchange_rate` isn't useful?

Comment: Unfortunately I never receive that field in response.

They say:
"Returned only in cross-currency use cases where a merchant bills a buyer in a non-primary currency for that buyer."

Actually the buyer pays in USD, but I get EUR. In that case is the merchant (me) that receive money in a non-primary currency.